# retrieve the path of a saved image causes crash

Tags: android, android-camera, mediastore

is it there a standard way to retrieve the path of an saves image taken by the camera, because i found different ways to display the path but they cause the App to crash.
and since i'm new to android programming i just need some guidance.
Please check the code:

**Java Code:**

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "My Images");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
            File image = new File(imagesFolder, "img01");
            uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
            File f = new File (uriSavedImage.getPath());// <---------
            //imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, f.getPath()); // <---------
            startActivityForResult(imageIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if ((requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),// <---------
                    " "+data.getData(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: can you paste the stack trace here ?

Answer (score 0):

It crashes because you pass `getParent()` to `convertImageUriToFile` method (you can see NullPointerException in the stacktrace). According to [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getParent%28%29) `getParent()` returns null if activity is not an embedded one. Yours most probably isn't.

Use `File f = convertImageUriToFile(uriSavedImage, this);` instead.

For another error, imageUri being null, see this [aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9775979/1210715) for very possible explanation and solution.

Morover, your imageUri is a "file://" type uri, not "content://" type.To get path from it, use

```
new File(uri.getPath());
```

instead of your `convertImageUriToFIle()` method. I think that method will work only for "content://" type uris.

Actually, you do not need to get the file path from uri you made yourself, you have that path in the line:

```
File image = new File(imagesFolder, "img01");
```

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        " "+convertImageUriToFile(uriSavedImage, this).getAbsolutePath(), 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   ` I tried to display the path as mentioned, but still the app crashs

Comment: Provide a stacktrace if you want help.

Comment: Isn't your imageUri null? There is nullPointerException during query execution. Check if you imageUri is not null and is in proper format (starts with content://)

Comment: i assign value to imageuri, but it's null

Comment: please check the code again i modified onActivityResult() method

Comment: i modified the code, please find it posted. But now the app doesnt crash and  it displays null. Note that, i'm using the emulator not a real device